# What data structure should I use to process large amounts of text data?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, text-processing

I'm trying to do some text classication using scikit-learn's TfidfVectorizer and the Nearest Neighbor algorithm.

I need to find similarity metrics between two data sets containing 18000 entries each. I'm unsure about what data structure can be best used to calculate what I think should be 18000*18000 similarity metrics.

I've only considered DataFrames so far.

Comment: Try a few out on a subset of your data and see which one works best for you.  It would be nice if the symantics of the container make your code easy to read.  What do scikit-learn examples use?

Comment: scikit-learn uses a lot of sparse matrices and DataFrames. I think either lists or DataFrames could work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any intermediate data for further analyses you can use a generator to hold your data points then run the algorithms through generators calls. Otherwise you'd probably want a list.